# Windows не видит Ubuntu 12.04 в сети

Tags: windows, samba, сеть, ubuntu

Гибридная сеть, ubuntu отлично видит windows, скачивает и удаляет файлы на удалённой машине, windows даже не видит ubuntu. Что делать, подскажите.

Comment: Какой протокол для доступа используете, что значит не видит? Больше информации нужно...

Comment: говоря:"не видит", я подразумевал, что находясь в "сетевом окружении" Windows комп с Ubuntu ни коим образом не отображался.Благодарю за устремление помочь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась неожиданным образом, после того как я (стыдно писать) расшарил папку на Ubuntu. Ubuntu попросил установить какие то пакеты после чего дал возможность расшарить ресурс. Осталось решить как сделать так чтобы с Windows можно было не только просматривать содержимое но и добавлять, но это уже другой вопрос (поставить соответствующую галку в разделе "общий доступ" это только пол дела).

Answer (score 2):

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/samba?s[]=опубликовать&s[]=папку

Answer (score 1):

> как сделать так чтобы с Windows можно было не только просматривать содержимое но и добавлять

777 на папку поставь и попробуй `Drag&drop` в неё с Винды что-нибудь.Если получится - отпиши, вместе по правам подумаем, как безопаснее сделать.